# Pros and Cons of Anemic Domain Model

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, anemic-domain-model

What are pros and cons of [Anemic Domain Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_Domain_Model) in your **experience**?
Despite what wiki says.

**Update:** I'm after answers that are based on experiences of this pattern applied in large scale enterprise applications!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/258534/337294) on stackoverflow.