# What is an anemic model?

Tags: model, domain-driven-design

I've been searching around for a while trying to understand just what this is, but I'm not really clear. What is an anemic model, and what is it an alternative to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically is an object model that has the semantic of the business, but the logic is implemented outside of the domain objet because it fails to encapsulate it.

The alternatice will be implementing the domain model properly. Of course the anemic model has some pros and cons:

[Anemic Domain Model: Pros/Cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258534/anemic-domain-model-pros-cons)

Also I foud this article very helpful: http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

I hope it helps!